# Call WinProlog on command prompt

Tags: cmd, prolog, prompt

I am trying to call a prolog file on windows prompt. The problem is that I always get a "yes message" and the window doesn't even close.
What am I doing wrong?

My "exemplo.pl" file:

run:-
    tell('output.txt'),
    write('Eu sou um exemplo!'),nl,
    told,
    halt.

:-run.

My console command:

PRO386W.EXE /V1 consult('exemplo.pl')

I used all kind of directories, but none of them work. Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

'halt'  halts Prolog.

Are you trying to get prolog to exit?

Assuming you are, then the problem is the way you've run it.

I used the same program with SWI-Prolog on win 7

with

```
run_me :- writeln('howdy annie'),halt.

:- run_me.
```

in somedir, I cd'ed into somedir and ran

swipl -s ihalt.pl

and it did just what was expected  -
printed the message and exited

I don't know what prolog you're using. if you're brand new to Prolog, www.swi-prolog.org is friendlier for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a . to the end:

```
PRO386W.EXE /V1 consult('exemplo.pl').
```